# Material UI <TextField/> not Vertical Align with it's Label

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui, textfield, typography

I want to vertically align the `Typography` and `TextField` of Material UI.
Here is my code

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
        <Typography>1.1 Company Name</Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={9}>
        <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here how it looks

[image]

Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: If you can remove the label prop it will make those two more align with each other. If you still want to keep the label then you will need to work with CSS directly

Answer (score 1):

you can use `alignItems="center"`

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you can apply  `align-items: flex-end;` to the container.

```
.MuiGrid-container {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Also make the template changes:-

```
<Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
        <Typography>1.1 Company Name</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
        <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-vaughan-kktty?file=/src/styles.css

[image]